# Alignment of UL in template footer (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

The problem is at the footer of my website. I was trying to make it look like the footer of the main template but I'm missing something which I can't understand. Please guide.

What I want it to look like:
[image: What I want it to look like:]

[image: What I'm getting]

please help to move the lists to a little back as shown in first picture.

Many Tanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have applied [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

You're missing `padding:0` to `ul` in the footer

This will help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing padding: 0px on the ul's in the footer. Apply it there and you get it done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.three.columns ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```